# kubernetes autoscale having issues with heapster

Tags: kubernetes

I have heapster installed on kubernetes, i am trying to autoscale my pods.. but i keep seeing the following:

```
unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
```

The heapster service itself

```
 I1009 14:22:21.014890       1 heapster.go:73] Heapster version v1.4.2
I1009 14:22:21.015226       1 configs.go:61] Using Kubernetes client with master "https://kubernetes.default" and version v1
I1009 14:22:21.015244       1 configs.go:62] Using kubelet port 10250
I1009 14:22:21.030070       1 heapster.go:196] Starting with Metric Sink
I1009 14:22:21.042806       1 heapster.go:106] Starting heapster on port 8082
E1009 14:30:05.000311       1 kubelet.go:280] Node ip-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal is not ready
E1009 14:30:05.000342       1 kubelet.go:280] Node ip-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal is not ready
E1009 14:30:05.000351       1 kubelet.go:280] Node ip-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal is not ready
E1009 14:30:05.000357       1 kubelet.go:280] Node ip-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal is not ready
E1009 14:30:05.000363       1 kubelet.go:280] Node ip-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal is not ready
E1009 14:30:05.000370       1 kubelet.go:280] Node ip-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal is not ready
```

I want to have autoscaling working with kubernetes, anyone have any ideas?

I know heapster is deprecated, but as of now i cannot chnage or upgrade to metrics server.. so could do with some help

Answer (score 1):

I have once seen similar error. The problem was RBAC issue but the error log was misleading. Make sure you have provided `get` permission for `pods.metrics.k8s.io` resource.

Check this similar question: [Kubernetes Custom CRD: “Failed to list …: the server could not find the requested resource”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021171/kubernetes-custom-crd-failed-to-list-the-server-could-not-find-the-reques)

> Note: Fetching metrics from Heapster is `deprecated` as of Kubernetes 1.11. Ref: [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)